# Ways to pull (potentially) large amounts of data from Twitter

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I've been playing around with the Twitter API using [Twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html). I am trying to pull data given a keyword and date, and example of a query I would run using the REST API would be

```
bagels since:2014-12-27
```

Which would give me all tweets containing the keyword 'bagels' since 2014-12-27.

This works in theory, but I've quickly exceeded the [rate limits](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits) since each query allows up to 100 results, and only 180 queries are allowed within a 15-minute interval. There are many keywords that return more than 18k results.

Is there a better way to pull large amounts of data from Twitter? I looked at the Streaming API but I don't know if I can pull data from a certain date range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can do to improve your rates:

1. Make sure your count is maxed at 100, which it looks like you're doing.
2. Use Application-Only authorization - it increases your rate limit to 450.
3. Use the max_id, since_id parameters to page through data and avoid querying for results you're already received. See the [Working with Timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines) docs to see what I mean.
4. Consider using Gnip if you're willing to pay to remove rate limits.